# Custom permalink structure leads to be 404 on pagination

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error

I have a permalink issue. For your information, there are a few different categories within a website and there are many posts in a single category.

My permalink setting is:

Custom Stucture: `/%category%/%postname%/`

Category Base: .

After this setting saved, my url will be

> www.mydomain.com/category-slug-name/

instead of

> www.mydomain.com/category/category-slug-name/

I have set the *Blog pages show at most: 8 posts* under the *Setting > Reading*. The pagination will appear when there are more than 8 posts in a category page.

I clicked on *"page 2"*, and noticed that `www.mydomain.com/category-slug-name/page/2/` brought me to 404 error page.

Originally, the url of any category "page2" is `www.mydomain.com/category/category-slug-name/page/2/`, it works fine if there is "category" within the url as original url. Or else, it would be 404 error page.

My main concern is, I don't want the category appear in the url. But i want the slug name of category appear in url when i viewing the selected post. And "/page/2/" and the rest will work fine.

Hopefully that this issue is not going to be resolved with recommended plugins. Because, I don't want the website to be too heavy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is totally normal behaviour. If you want to remove category base you will need to write some custom rewrite rules, not simple rules I must say. From my point of view, removing category base requires a extra job in each request that is worthless because it doesn't provide any advantage for SEO or for better site navigation. Some popular plugins, like WordPres SEO by Yoast, had this option in the past and removed it some time ago. But this is just an opinion.

Configure category base to `.` (dot), put this code in the functions.php of your theme, or better in a plugin, and flush the rewrite rules (code from [this post in Daily Web Kit](http://dailywebkit.com/blog/remove-category-best-options/)):

```
add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules' );
function vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $categories = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    if ( is_array( $categories ) && ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        $slugs = array();
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            if ( is_object( $category ) && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) {
                if ( 0 == $category->category_parent ) {
                    $slugs[] = $category->slug;
                } else {
                    $slugs[] = trim( get_category_parents( $category->term_id, false, '/', true ), '/' );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $slugs ) ) {
            $rules = array();

            foreach ( $slugs as $slug ) {
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)?/?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')(/page/(\d)+/?)?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]';
            }
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I have done accordingly to your instructions. But, the "/page/2" is still not working. Is there any other solution to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: I tested the code before post it and it works. Please, as it is said in the answer, remember to flush the rewrite rules (after copy and save the code, go to settings->permalinks and click on "save". This will make that WordPress rebuild the rewrite rules taking in account the new ones).

Comment: Hi! I tried. Your code for function is work. But, cannot put the "dot" into the category base, and i need to use the "301 Redirect" to redirect all the "domain.com/category/category-slug-name/" to "domain.com/category/category-slug-name/". Only the "/page/2/" work by then.

Comment: I tested with the "dot" into the category base as you see in the answer, in fact that dot is needed. You didn't talk about any redirection and the way you have implemented the redirection is unknown to me, that is another issue that needs another thread.

Comment: Hi Cybmeta, the dot is really not working at my end. it's okay! By the way, thank for your help, too. I will still vote for your answer as you helped me. :)

Comment: It is better if we find the solution ;). You said in the question that the "dot" is working and I don't understand why it is not working now; the code posted in the answer hanlde pagination and feeds but it has nothing to do with the "dot". When you say that it doesn't work, do you mean that it doesn't work if you use the code from the answer or it doesn't work even without that code?

Comment: The "/page/2/ & more pages" don't work(redirect to 404) if i insert the "dot" inside the field of "Category Base" after your code applied to my functions.php file. The "/page/2/ & more pages" work fine after i removed the "dot" from the field of "Category Base". But, the condition to make it work is, i need to use rewrite the rule in my htaccess file to redirect the "/category/category-slug-name" to "/slug-name/".

Comment: **Have you flushed the rewrite rules after apply the code?**. As I said, the code posted is working fine here. Maybe you have more code affecting the category rewrite rules. Try it with all plugins deactivated and with a default theme. By the way, the redirection in htaccess file should be done **only** if you are in a live site that was using the old URL structure in the past in order to not lose SEO ranking and to not lose users that come from a old URL; making that redirection in a new site is worthless.

Comment: Yes! I did tried accordingly to your instructions. But, it didn't work.

Comment: Worked as advertised for me. Also thank you for putting the code directly in your answer as the blog link is no longer valid.

Comment: **There is a bug in this answer** if pagination doesn't work for you - page  10 and more => fix: change this `(\d)+` to this `(\d+)` and go to Permalinks setttings and re-save... (flush rewrite rules)

Answer (score 3):

This Worked for me, 
Add this function in your functions.php page in wordpress and this function will change your like:

Previous: http://www.example.com/advice/category/category_name/page/3/

To: http://www.example.com/advice/category_name/page/3/

```
function remove_category_slug_url($query_string){ 
    if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
        unset($query_string['name']);
        list($delim, $page_index) = explode('/', $query_string['page']);
        $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
    }      
    return $query_string;
}
add_filter('request', 'remove_category_slug_url');
```

Comment: thats somehow just displaying posts of the first page on all my other follow pages...

Answer (score 1):

```
function 
 remove_category_slug_url($query_string){ 
if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
    unset($query_string['name']);
    list($delim, $page_index) = split('/', $query_string['page']);
    $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
}      
return $query_string;
 }
 add_filter('request', 'remove_category_slug_url');
```

This Worked for me, Add this function code in your functions.php in wordpress

note: go to settings->permalinks and click on "save". This will make that WordPress rebuild the rewrite rules taking in account the new ones

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
function remove_page_from_query_string($query_string){ 
   if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
       unset($query_string['name']);
       // 'page' in the query_string looks like '/2', so i'm spliting it out
      list($delim, $page_index) = split('/', $query_string['page']);
      $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
   }      
   return $query_string;
} 
add_filter('request', 'remove_page_from_query_string');
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, with the redirects on paginated pages, the following worked for me:

In your permalinks, change: 
/%category%/%postname%/

to

/%category%/%postname%

Notice the removal of the ending forward slash "/".

Rob