# Pagination 404 error(I have refreshed the permalinks and tried several previous options)

Tags: php, functions, pagination

I am using pagination in wordpress, the truth is that I have used it several times. But this time, when I access page number 2, I get an error 404. I've searched a bit and I've tried several functions, but not work.
Here I leave my loop

```
 <?php

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $news = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_name' => 'projekte',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 8
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($news);
        if (have_posts()) :
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                <div class="column is-one-quarter">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <div class="thecontent">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-container">
                                <div class="subtitle">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="contain">
                                    <p><?php the_field('beschreibung'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '/page/%#%',
                    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'show_all' => true,
                    'end_size' => 1,
                    'mid_size' => 2,
                    'prev_next' => true,
                    'prev_text' => __(''),
                    'next_text' => __(''),
                    'type' => 'plain',
                    'add_args' => false,
                    'add_fragment' => '',
                    'before_page_number' => '',
                    'after_page_number' => ''
                ));
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I hope someone can help me, because I'm under pressure and I feel blocked.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried saving your permalinks. Please go to Settings > Permalinks in WP Admin and click Save Changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress /page/2 404 pagination problem - what to do?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209693/wordpress-page-2-404-pagination-problem-what-to-do)

Comment: Here's a good read as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189247/why-pagination-is-not-working-and-gives-a-404-error-on-the-wordpress-site. On what page or post exactly are you displaying the results of your custom query? You may need to adjust the main query via `pre_get_posts`, so that WordPress globally knows aha oho what query exactly is running on that page right now, will it have pages or should I trigger a 404 as not every page should simply be accessible with a `*/page/*` URL.

Comment: I've tried it before, it does not give me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

First, in functions.php:

```
function mg_news_pagination_rewrite() {
add_rewrite_rule(get_option('category_base').'/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php? 
pagename='.get_option('category_base').'&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'mg_news_pagination_rewrite');
```

and then in wordpress, settings> Permalinks changes must be saved